# Error to Install npm install -g cordova ionic

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm-install

I design an app using ionic. When I install cordova using node.js I face these problems.

```
C:\Users\KSS>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\KSS\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5012-d
4aedd8a\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-2.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: cc4218ec13f31b635c1119c9defae5b2bad31335
npm ERR! Actual:   88177629627a16987bec942611d1ca9e69b8aba9
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.1.0.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: Did you open console as Administrator since sometimes same error occurs while installing globally without root access?

Comment: update npm to `3.9.*`

Comment: @abdulbarik problem is same there:(

Comment: @iamrealshu problem is same there:(

Answer (score 1):

The checksum failed `npm ERR! shasum check failed`

You can try upgrading to the latest version of npm :

```
npm install -g npm
```

To upgrade to npm 3.

Also :

```
npm cache clean
```

and

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

As work for some https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701

Comment: Thanks ... Buddy. Its Work Successfully